# H2 and query logging?

Tags: database, logging, h2

Is there a way to get a "query log" out of H2, like you can with e.g. MySQL? The closest match so far is the TRACE_LEVEL_FILE option, but it it not good for debugging the individual queries, especially when they have variable parameters like most do.

Answer (score 17):

The `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE` is the best option. There are 4 levels:

- 0 (disabled)
- 1 (only errors)
- 2 (errors and info messages, including SQL statements)
- 3 (debug level; including SQL statements and parameter values)
- 4 (log using SLF4J)

So I guess 2 would be the right level in your case.

There is also a simple way to analyze the trace file, documented in [Database Profiling](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#database_profiling).