# How to trace SQL requests for H2 in-memory databases?

Tags: h2, slf4j, logback

How can I trace SQL requests for H2 in-memory embedded databases?

The documentation says the trace file is located in the same directory as the database file, but for in-memory embedded database I have no database directory (under Windows).

I tried to redirect traces to a given file with slf4j/logback by using

```
TRACE_LEVEL_FIle=4;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=3
```

in the database URL and the following logback.xml config file but with no luck:

```
<configuration scan="true">
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>mylogfile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>%d{yyyyMMdd}_mylogfile.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss} %contextName[%thread] %level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.myapp" level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="h2database" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger> -->

  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

My logback config file works correctly for other logs.

Any idea?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124886/h2-and-query-logging

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but according to my test it seems if you remove `TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=3` then it would work. Could you try this? Example database URL:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4
```

instead of

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=3
```

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it work correctly with a unit test. The problem seems to come from the application I'm using which connects directly to the database and its logging configuration (using commons logging) that makes the logs always redirected to console and not to the log file as I want.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum trace level is 3 (check source code), that's why it failed in your case

Comment: In 1.4.200 this is definitely not true. This is from the [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options): `To enable SLF4J, set the file trace level to 4 in the database URL`.